# ¿Como traducir "for 1 month" en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy utilizando Wordpress, Woocommerce y Subscription para vender mis suscripciones, el asunto es que cuando se quiere comprar una suscripcion en el checkout aparece "$100,00 for 1 month", me gustaria ponerlo en español. ¿Que debo hacer para traducirlo?. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente enlace se explica el proceso:

https://www.luislar.es/como-traducir-woocommerce-al-espanol-en-solo-4-pasos/

Basicamente se requieren unos archivos extension .mo y .po y realizar una configuracion en las opciones del plugin.

Los archivos .mo y .po contienen las traducciones al español de cada frase utilizada por el plugin como por ejemplo: "for 1 month".

Tambien puedes apoyarte con el plugin Loco Translate para ajustar las traducciones a tu gusto:

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/